# How to sync CLIENT_ID across different serving methods of amp pages?

Tags: amp-html, amp-analytics

An AMP page can be served from google search cache inside an iframe using the amp cache/proxy, or directly from amp cache/proxy, or directly from the page URL. How can I sync the amp-analytics CLIENT_ID across these all methods?

I can sync direct amp and non-amp page since the cookie would be saved on the same domain. How to do it in other cases?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using AMP Variable Substitutions?
Here - https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-var-substitutions.md#client-id

i.e. -

```
Example usage: ${clientId('fallback-cookie-name')}
Example value: amp-Us3yaeQyR2DKATQH1pTZ6kg140fvuLbtl5nynbUWtIodJxP5TEIYBic4qcV
```

From the documentation ( https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/optimize-and-measure/configure-analytics/analytics_basics/ ) -

> AMP manages reading and writing of the client ID in all cases. This is particularly notable in the case when a page is served via a cache or otherwise shown outside the viewing context of the publisher's original site. In this circumstance, access to the publisher site's cookies is unavailable.
>
> When an AMP page is served from a publisher's site, the client ID framework that AMP uses can be told about a fallback cookie to look for and use. In this case, the cid-scope-cookie-fallback-name argument of the clientId variable is interpreted as a cookie name. The formatting may appear as either CLIENT_ID(cid-scope-cookie-fallback-name) or ${clientId(cid-scope-cookie-fallback-name)}